# C++ / Arduino: How to access an object from a subclass

Tags: c++, arduino

I attached a Shift Register to my Ardunio and created an own class for it. From the *main* file I am creating an object like this

```
ShiftRegister myRegister;

//myRegister.begin(int arduinoPin, int state);
myRegister.begin(int 8, int LOW);

myRegister.write(1, HIGH);
```

This works fine to far. By calling the *begin()* method, I get my Shift Register object with 8 own pins. I can directly switch the output of my Shift Register via the *write()* method (in this case pin 1 of the Shift Register).

Now a have a device attached to the Shift Register. I create it from the main file via

```
Device myDevice;

myDevice.switchOn();
```

I will need to tell the device, which Shift Register Pin it is connected to. Something like

```
myDevice.begin(5);
```

Afterwards I would like to only call the function *myDevice.switchOn()* to turn the device on. So I don't want to do it directly by *myRegister.write(5, HIGH)*, but rather from the Device class.

How do I make class Device do that? So far this class does not know anything about the Shift Register. By pointers? What would be the concrete way?

I am quite new to C++/Arduino, so forgive me in case this might be a rather trivial question. Also I am not too deep in object oriented programming yet...

Comment: Is a change to your `ShiftRegister` supposed immediately propagate to all `Device`s that are connected to that `ShiftRegister` and so affect all the `Device`s pins - or are you supposed to manually go through all `Device`s an call `switchOn()`? Btw, `switchOn` is a bad name since you don't know if it'll switch on or off since that's stored in the `ShiftRegister`. Also, should two `Device`s be able to be connected to the same pin while using the same `ShiftRegister` or should that be detected and refused?

Comment: Did you abandon this question? If none of the answers answer your question, ask follow up questions to the answers or clarify your question. One clarification could be to answer the question I asked above almost a week ago.

Answer (score 2):

I am no familiar with arduino components, but..

You can extend the device class:

```
class DeviceWithShiftReference: public Device{

    private: ShiftRegister * myShiftReference;

    public: DeviceWithShiftReference(ShiftRegister* reg) {
        myShiftReference = reg
    }

    public: doSomething() {
        // here you can perform stuff with the shift register inside your device 
    }
};

void main(void){
    ShiftRegister myRegister;
    DeviceWithShiftReference myDevice(&myRegister);
    myDevice.doSomething();
}
```

In this way you keep a reference to your register inside your class, from doSomething() you can deference myShiftReference and perform actions with:

```
myShiftRegister->begin( ... )
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo what do you mean by does not work? Compile errors?

Comment: Yes, it's not valid C++. `private: <all private members>` and `public: <all public members>` will work though. You typically only need one `private:` and one `public:`. Also, your member functions need types.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Oh yeah sorry, it is a typo my bad. I will edit the answer

Comment: @TedLyngmo mark it as correct if it solves your issue ;)

Comment: @TedLyngmo with this method you can implement a doSomething (e.g. switchOn()) function where you perform actions on the shift register right inside the DeviceWithShiftReference class. I do not know if Device is a class you implemented or it is part of the arduino framework, that's why I suggested inheritance. You my reimplement Device if you can with the pointer to register method and achieve the same result

Comment: Hmm, I have not implemented any of it and I don't have any issues with it. I asked OP for clarification on how it's supposed to work under the question in order to be able to make an answer myself. Btw, I suggest you make your constructor `DeviceWithShiftReference(ShiftRegister& reg) : myShiftReference(&reg) {}` to not have to check if a `nullptr` is supplied.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yeah passing by reference makes more sense here, though once reference is assigned you cannot change it, pointers gives you more freedom and generality

Comment: Note that I just suggested passing it by reference. You still store a pointer in your class (`myShiftReference(&reg)`).

Answer (score 0):

You could add a couple of parameters to your Device class constructor, one parameter being a pointer to your ShiftRegister object, and the other being which pin it is on.  These two parameters you save internally in the object.

```
class Device 
{
  public:
    Device(ShiftRegister *pReg, int iPin)
    {
      reg = pReg;
      pin = iPin;
    }
  private:
    int pin;
    ShiftRegister *reg;
}
```

Then you can do

```
ShiftRegister myRegister;
myRegister.initStuff(...);
Device  myDevice(&myRegister, 5);
.
.
myDevice.switchOff();  // Uses the saved pin value
myDevice.switchOn();
```

Comment: I suggest: `Device(ShiftRegister *pReg, int iPin) : reg(pReg), pin(iPin)  {}` and switch the order of member variables. Also, providing a `ShiftRegister` becomes optional if the constructor takes it as a pointer. I suggest that you take it by reference and then just _store_ a pointer instead. `Device(ShiftRegister& rReg, int iPin) : reg(&rReg), pin(iPin) {}`